# Multiprocessing, return object dynamically from processes and update progress bar Python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

We currently have a main program that take a lot of time on making calculations to create custom objects, we wanted to use more power from threading and processing, we tried to use Threads  but it's finally a bad idea because of GIL.

I am now trying to use Multiprocessing, using a process class that can make calculations then return an object through a results queue, but we don't want our main program to wait for each process to complete and freeze during this time, we want to use a Progress Bar because those calculations are taking a lot of time, we need to inform the UI.

That's why I'm trying to use a "master" process which start others, then wait for them instead of the main program.

What we are trying to achieve :
- We first create a subProcess (from main) that will to start others (dataProcess), then wait for them to complete.
- When a dataProcess is ended, it add the object to a result queue that subProcess can see, then... Here we are, we need a way to pass this object to the main Program then it can update progress and more. (Main Program already know how much Object he need to receive to get 100%)

Here is the actual simplified code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, Queue, cpu_count

class dataProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue, result):
        self.queue = queue
        self.result = result
        Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
    while 1:
        object = self.queue.get()
        if object is None:
            self.queue.task_done()
            break

        # Working with object and creating an object as a result

        self.queue.task_done()
        self.result.put(result)


class subProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, objectList):
        self.objects = objectList
        Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
                self.queue = JoinableQueue()
                self.result_queue = Queue()
                self.processes = cpu_count()

                for object in self.objects:
                    self.queue.put(object)

                for i in range(self.processes):
                    self.queue.put(None)

                for i in range(self.nbProcess):
                    process = dataProcess(self.queue, self.result_queue)
                    process.start()
                    print "New Process Start"

                while 1:
                    for object in iter(self.result_queue.get, None):
                        if object.complete: # Boolean attribute of my object, true when dataProcess is done
                            print "complete !"
                            # Now I need to send this freshly new object to the main program !
                            # Main program can update a QProgressbar and can use the object

                self.queue.join()
```

Using a Thread instead of Process for our "subProcess" is working fine while debuging but it just freeze UI indefinitely with Python IDLE (It probably can use only 1 Thread at a time, then it freeze UI)

Is there any way to perform this ?

Thanks for answers

Edit :
I'm running the subProcess by only doing :

```
process = subProcess(objectList)
process.start()
```

(Inside a QMainWindow)

With a Thread I would use a signal, something like :

```
    thread = subThread(objectList)
    self.connect(thread, SIGNAL("end"), self.receiveObject)
    thread.start()

def receiveObject(self, object):
    # Do whatever we need
```

Comment: Can you include the code that instantiates and runs `subProcess`?

Comment: Does it work ok if you run the script outside of IDLE?

Comment: @dano No, if I use a "subThread" (pretty the same code, I just call my signal after "print "complete !") it freeze, it only work on Pydev debugger, subProcess should work as it's not using a second Thread for the app, but you can see I don't know how to send an object back like a thread would do when I'm using subProcess.

Comment: @dano Success, If I use a "subThread" it finally work, but I need to store the subThread object where I'm calling it using self.process = subProcess(objectList), that's working fine, I don't know why it work without that while Debugging. Well, then it work with a "master" thread starting processes, except that processes are slow to start, but it does not answer to "how to do the same with processes", performance might be better with subProcess instead of a subThread, any ideas ?

Comment: @Retsim is `subThread` a `QThread`? `QThread` objects get destroyed as soon as they go out of scope, which is why it wasn't working when you didn't save the `subThread` object as an instance variable. I think any solution you some up with is going to require either a dedicated thread listening to the result queue, or a recurring function that gets called in the main thread by the event loop, which does non-blocking checks of the queue.

Comment: @dano Yep, QThread, good to know ! It was closing but `def __del__(self):
        self.wait()` was against this idea, that's why it was freezing. Listening to a result queue is what I'm doing in my subProcess class (and subThread as well) and it's fine, I'm just wondering now if there is any better way to do this, performance is a big deal for us. Thanks for your help !